# How to write jQuery code to return an attribute value by searching for another attribute?

Tags: jquery, xml

I have an xml object like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
- <fxf version="1.0" data="hold">
  - <report records="168" lines="168" columns="15" rows="168">
    <target format="" version="" type="" destination="HOLD" /> 
    - <column_desc>
      <col colnum="c0" fieldname="FUND_NAME_DISP" datatype="char"/> 
      <col colnum="c1" fieldname="FUND_CODE" datatype="char"/> 
      <col colnum="c2" fieldname="FUND_NAME" datatype="char"/> 
      <col colnum="c3" fieldname="FUND_CODE_2" datatype="char"/> 
      <col colnum="c4" fieldname="FUND_NAME_2" datatype="char"/> 
      <col colnum="c5" fieldname="CURRENCY" datatype="char"/> 
   </column_desc>
  </report>
</fxf>
```

I need to write a jQuery function to return the "colnum" attribute by searching for "fieldname" attribute. for example

```
   $.searchCol(myXml,'CURRENCY') will return "c5".
```

This is what my draft code looks like:

```
$.searchCol = function(xml, search_field_name){
    var colNode  = $('column_desc col', xml).first();
    while(colNode.length){
           if(colNode.attributes['fieldname']==search_field_name){
              return colNode.attributes['colnum'];  
           }
           colNode.next();
    };
    return null
 })
```

But colNode.attributes does not return the collection of all attributes in the node.

Please help...

Comment: Based on your code, it looks like you only grab the first column when you call `.first()` on your query selector.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/6zWTf/)

```
function find(where, what) {
    return $($.parseXML(where))
             .find('col[fieldname=' + what + ']')
             .attr('colnum');   
}

console.log(find(xml, 'CURRENCY')); //c5
```

Comment: This is great! I've been searching for "xml" and "attribute". Many returned the "attributes" collection, but not ".parseXML". Need to do some digging, thanks!